# Sorting array of number by decimal

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, methods

I am trying to find out how to sort an array of number by decimal.
I am this array

```
[9, 9.10, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9]
```

By using sort 9.1 is before 9.2 but what I neeed is to have 9.1 after 9.9 so the order will be as below:
`9, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 9,10`

How can I force doing that?

Thanks

Comment: What is the logic behind `9.1` being sorted after `9.9`? Wouldn’t it make more sense to sort these as _strings_ rather than numbers?

Comment: So you do not have numbers, but strings because `9.10` === `9.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to work with them as string and not numbers. You need to split them into two parts and do the comparisons based on the parts, not the wholes.

```js
var items = ['9', '9.10', '9.2', '9.3', '9.9', '8', '7', '6'];
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  const partsA = a.split(".");
  const partsB = b.split(".");
  if (partsA[0] === partsB[0]) {
    return partsA[1] === partsB[1] ? 0 : (+partsA[1] || 0) > (+partsB[1] || 0) ? 1 : -1;
  }

  return +partsA[0] > +partsB[0] ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(items);
```